# IIS: WCF service with https and GET -> HTTP 400 Error

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, https, get

I am trying to create a WCF Service for https binding. The service was working with http before. I changed the binding (with certificate) and now I configure the web.config - but I always get error code "400 - Bad Request".

The web service is called with: 
https://servername:444/FolderService.svc/FolderExists/1234
https://servername:444/FolderService.svc/Test

This is my service interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IFolderService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/FolderExists/{accountnumber}")]
    bool FolderExists(string accountnumber);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/Test")]
    string Test();
}
```

And this is my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="myService.FolderService">
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="secureHttpBinding"
                  contract="myService.IFolderService"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="secureHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

I tried so many different configuration without success. Does anyone have an idea (or a working example)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access your methods in a RESTful manner via a URL. However, what you have wrong in your web.config is that you are using `BasicHttpBinding` which is for SOAP web services and not RESTful web services.

`WebGet` and `WebInvoke` are the necessary attributes to add to your operations as you have already done.

However, the correct binding for the endpoint is `WebHttpBinding` and the behavior you need to apply to the endpoint is the `WebHttpBehavior`.

**Sample Abbreviated Configuration:**

```
<service> 
    <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior" 
              binding="webHttpBinding" 
              contract="myService.IFolderService" 
              bindingConfiguration="secureHttpBinding" /> 
</service> 

<endpointBehaviors> 
    <behavior name="webBehavior"> 
        <webHttp /> 
    </behavior> 
</endpointBehaviors>
```